# Cocoa : Blinking item before closing the menu

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, menu

When clicking on a Menu item on OSX, the item blinks (on-off-on-close) once before the menu closes.

I was asking my self how can mimic that behavior ? (I've reimplemented a Menu using NSCollectionView, selection & clic on item both work)

I tried 2 thinks that did not work :

```
mouseOver = false;
[self drawRect:self.bounds];
mouseOver = true;
[self drawRect:self.bounds];

[[self window] performSelector:@selector(orderOut:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

and

```
mouseOver = false;
[self setNeedsDisplayInRect:self.bounds];
[self needsDisplay];
mouseOver = true;
[self setNeedsDisplayInRect:self.bounds];
[self needsDisplay];

[[self window] performSelector:@selector(orderOut:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went for that solution :

```
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [super mouseDown:theEvent];

    [self performSelector:@selector(blinkItemOnce:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] afterDelay:0.0];
    [self performSelector:@selector(blinkItemOnce:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] afterDelay:0.05];
    [[self window] performSelector:@selector(orderOut:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.15];
}

-(void) blinkItemOnce:(NSNumber*) b {
    mouseOver = [b boolValue];
    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:self.bounds];
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```